# How to fix this error "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in..."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as t,
    t1.EMPLID, 
    t3.DNI,
    t1.PUNCH_DTTM,
    PUNCH_TYPE,
    TCD_ID,
    t2.PCADescripcion,
    t2.DFIDescripcion,
    t2.Alias,
    t5.apellido,
    t4.planta
FROM 
    [MatrizDB].[db_owner].[Historial_TRH] t1
LEFT JOIN 
    MatrizDB.db_owner.Dispositivos_TRH t2 ON t2.RefId = TCD_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    MatrizDB.db_owner.Pipolsoft_Legajos t3 ON t3.EMPLID = t1.EMPLID
LEFT JOIN 
    [MatrizDB].[dbo].[nomina_fase_two] t4 ON t4.dni_id = t3.DNI 
LEFT JOIN 
    [MatrizDB].dbo.v_nomina t5 ON t5.nroDocumento = t4.dni_id
WHERE  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), PUNCH_DTTM, 120) LIKE '2019-04-24%' 
    AND t4.dni_responsable = 30329134 
    AND PUNCH_TYPE = 5
```

When I execute the query, I get this error

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you want to do, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: See [the many questions already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+%22is+invalid+in+the+select+list+because+it+is+not+contained+in%22)

Comment: Welcome do SO, pls before posting a question make a search on SO, Google, SQL Documentation. Seriously, you just forgot the group by clause. Also read the help section with tips to write a good question

Answer (score 4):

You have `count(*)` in the `select`, so your query is an aggregation query. You have no `group by`; an aggregation query with no `group by` returns *exactly* one row. What values should be in that row for the other columns?

One answer is to put all the non-aggregated columns in the `group by`.  Another is to remove all the non-aggregated columns from the `select`.  Another would be to replace the `count(*)` with a window function (say, `count(*) over ()` or what I suspect you want is `row_number() over (order by <some column>)`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to put group by as you used aggregate function `count`

```
SELECT 
       count(*) as t
      ,t1.EMPLID
     ,t3.DNI
      ,t1.PUNCH_DTTM
      ,PUNCH_TYPE
      ,TCD_ID
      ,t2.PCADescripcion
      ,t2.DFIDescripcion
      ,t2.Alias
      ,t5.apellido
      ,t4.planta

  FROM [MatrizDB].[db_owner].[Historial_TRH] t1
      left join MatrizDB.db_owner.Dispositivos_TRH t2
        on t2.RefId = TCD_ID
     left join MatrizDB.db_owner.Pipolsoft_Legajos t3
        on t3.EMPLID = t1.EMPLID
     left join [MatrizDB].[dbo].[nomina_fase_two] t4
        on t4.dni_id = t3.DNI 
     left join [MatrizDB].dbo.v_nomina t5
        on t5.nroDocumento = t4.dni_id
  where  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),PUNCH_DTTM,120) LIKE '2019-04-24%' 
         AND t4.dni_responsable = 30329134 and PUNCH_TYPE = 5
  group by t1.EMPLID
     ,t3.DNI
      ,t1.PUNCH_DTTM
      ,PUNCH_TYPE
      ,TCD_ID
      ,t2.PCADescripcion
      ,t2.DFIDescripcion
      ,t2.Alias
      ,t5.apellido
      ,t4.planta
```